# How to force postfix to use ip that is configured for domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, spf, dkim

I want to confirm to SPF and DKIM, this requires me to send email using the IP written in the DNS record of the domain

I have two domains example1.com and example2.com with two IPs 100.0.0.1 and 100.0.0.2 respectively.

How can I configure postfix to always use IP 100.0.0.1 when the send from address is xx@example1.com and the same to be true for the other domain.

When connecting to the SMTP transport I am using localhost, I know I can configure two postfix instances for each IP and then just connect to the right IP when sending depending on the domain, I would like to see if this can be avoided.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why not just add both IPs in SPF using `include:otherdomain.tld`? DKIM has nothing to do with the IP address afaik.

Comment: I did not think about that, what about reverse DNS issue, when reverse DNSing one ip, the domains will not match, some MTA's use SPF some use PTR some use reverse dns rDNS, how can this be solved?

Comment: I am not aware about MTAs actually matching the rDNS record, I only know about verify their *existence*.

Comment: I mean they see if ip 1 matches the domain 1, because if they don't check it's very easy to fool them for spammers

Comment: Nope. Somebody has been telling you a fairytale I guess. Those checks on the source IP for mail are done using SPF, possibly against a DNSBL (also PBL), possibly for acceptance of the `Return-Path` sender address given, but not on a 'match' for the latter one on rDNS. That would break all ways of doing mail relay by a 3rd party (e.g. Amazon SES).

Answer (score 1):

May take some fiddling, but i think you can achieve this in the following way:

- configure your original smtpd listener in master.cf to route mail where sender is from each respective domain to two new, local smtpd listeners
- setup 2 additional smtpd listeners in master.cf that have their own main.cf files (eg. example1.main.cf and example2.main.cf) :http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html (in said master.cf file, you can override various settings for main.cf via the -o name=value mechanism)
- configure the new main.cf files with appropriate outbound interface configurations and other related main.cf configs

Answer (score 0):

You can specify sender as user@example1.com and user@example2.com to send mails from an Ip/Host by using sender dependent sasl authentication. Follow these links. http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_sender And in other terms. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postfix-multiple-isp-accounts-smarthost-smtp-client/